# ftplib is missing in openshift

Tags: python, python-2.7, openshift, ftplib

I'm having application using python 2.7 in openshift and trying to copy file using ftplib.

When I try it in local virtenv everything is OK. But after deployment on openshift getting 500 on web site. Removing code related to ftplib makes it working (it is enough to comment out import ftplib).

It looks like openshift is missing ftplib. Anybody with similar problem? How to get it there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added it to your dependencies for your application?

Python now supports the use of requirements.txt to handle your dependencies, although python handles things a little different from php/perl. Your requirements.txt can be in your app’s root directory. If both your setup.py and requirements.txt exist within your repo, then both will be processed.

Comment: I'm having setup.py file with install_requires=['flask==0.10.1','flask-login==0.2.7','sqlalchemy==0.8.2','flask-sqlalchemy==1.0', 'MarkupSafe', 'ftplib'],
     )

Comment: Can you try to ssh into the server, and run virtualenv manually and try to install ftplib to see if you get an error? Or check your error logs

Comment: i did git push again and from console: remote: Searching for ftplib
remote: Reading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/simple/ftplib/
remote: Couldn't find index page for 'ftplib' (maybe misspelled?)
remote: Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
remote: Reading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/simple/
remote: No local packages or download links found for ftplib
remote: error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ftplib')

Comment: Since ftplib seems to be part of the python standard library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) I don't think you need to include it in that list?  It should just be available.

Comment: yes that was my thoughts as well, but it didn't work. It doesn't work with ftplib in install_requires either. So i guess there is something wrong with openshift.

Comment: It should not need to be installed at all, don't list it anywhere and see if it works, since it's part of python, it's not a package you install.  I am able to ssh to my openshift gear, run "python" and run the line 'from ftplib import FTP' without any errors, which means that it should work fine.

Comment: it does not help. it seems like openshift is missing this library.